# Why does React use State not display img by default?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a code that should change the banner under certain circumstances, and it does, but I want useState to leave the banner by default when the conditions are not met, but it does not see it. Although when I output its value to the console, it works for manual input.

```
 import {useState } from "react";
 import banner from '/public/images/banner.webp'
    
 export function MainBanner() {
    
   const [pic, setPic] = useState(`${banner.src}`)
```

CSS:

```
 .banner {
                        display:flex; 
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 600px;
                        justify-content: center;
                        background-blend-mode: darken;
                        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
                        background-position: center center;
                        background-image: url('${pic}');
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-size:cover;   
         }
```

The problem is that the default value is not visible and is equal to :
[image]

When the condition is not met useState should leave the default path to the banner, why doesn't it see the default path? When I output it to the console, by default it is /_next/static/media/banner.5954803e.webp and if I put it in css without using useState, then everything works

Comment: Where are you writing your CSS? Is it in a separate file or are you using styled components?

Comment: style JSX in component

Answer (score 2):

You can use console.log(banner) to view your imported "banner" and you will see it is a string like "/static/media/...", which is the url string you can used as the url content.

So you can use "banner" below:

```
const [pic, setPic] = useState(banner)

.banner {
  background-image: url(`${pic}`);
}
```

Update:
use inline style

```
<Banner style={{backgroundImage: `url(${pic})`}}/>
```

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/component/MainBanner.tsx
Error: error: Expression expected
  
   |
83 |         <>
   |          ^

error: Expected ',', got 'jsx'
  
   |
94 |             <style jsx>{`
   |                    ^^^

Caused by:
    0: failed to process js file
    1: Syntax Error                                                                                                                                When    background-image: url(`${pic}`);

Comment: you can use inline style in your component like my update

Answer (score 0):

The statement `import banner from '/public/images/banner.webp'` refers to the exported content of the file, in this case, the banner itself. So, `${banner.src}` will always be `undefined`. You can directly set the path in `useState` itself, like this:

```
const [pic, setPic] = useState(`/_next/static/media/banner.5954803e.webp`)
```